# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor replacement?

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

On the MS website itself they advice to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` namespace for building custom tags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-6.0

However `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` is deprecated in Nuget. Any idea what to sue instead?

Answer (score 0):

If a Nuget package will be deprecated, it means that there is already a solution to replace it, which may be integrated within the framework, or there may be a new Nuget package.

I'm not sure why you need to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` Namespace when customizing TagHelper, but its role is to provide support classes for the design-time and runtime experience of the Razor language. And In subsequent .net versions, the [ASP.NET Core Razor SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is included, which will be applied to your application by default:

> The Razor SDK:
>
> Is required to build, package, and publish projects containing Razor files for ASP.NET Core MVC-based or Blazor projects.
>
> Includes a set of predefined properties, and items that allow customizing the compilation of Razor (.cshtml or .razor) files.

Of course, if it's just custom tags, I think [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers?view=aspnetcore-7.0) may be more appropriate.

If you have other logic that must use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor`, you can provide a minimal reproducible example.